# Notes & Files related questions

Tags: apex, lightning, notes

Have a few queries regarding the new Notes . I have searched a few documentation . But havn't foun how this can be removed?

How can we restrict Notes sharing option for any particular profile?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Notes do not have any associated permissions that we can set directly. The best you can do is to remove it from the page layout entirely. Do notice, however, that there are [rules for how notes work](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=notes_del.htm&type=5). In addition, you can write a trigger to prevent notes from being created, edited, or deleted in more restrictive ways than the default permissions allow. For example, you could write a trigger to block deletion of notes from a particular profile.